# Mapping home controller as the default controller in AltoRouter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, composer-php, router, altorouter

This is the **index.php**

```
<?php
include 'library/altorouter.php';

$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->setBasePath('/AltoRouter'); 

$router->map('GET','/', 'home_controller#index', 'home');
$router->map('GET','/content/[:parent]/?[:child]?', 'content_controller#display_item', 'content');

$match = $router->match();

// not sure if code after this comment  is the best way to handle matched routes
list( $controller, $action ) = explode( '#', $match['target'] );

if ( is_callable(array($controller, $action)) ) {

    $obj = new $controller();

     var_dump($obj);

    call_user_func_array(array($obj,$action), array($match['params']));

} else if ($match['target']==''){
    echo 'Error: no route was matched'; 

} else {
    echo 'Error: can not call '.$controller.'#'.$action; 

}

// content_controller class file is autoloaded 

class home_controller {
    public function index() {
        echo 'hi from home';
    }
}
```

and it works good. The home_controller class is supposed to be the default controller.

Problem is, when I remove the class home_controller

```
class home_controller {
    public function index() {
        echo 'hi from home';
    }
}
```

and save it as a seprate file **home_controller.php** in **app/controller** directroy it does not work.

I understand that the router is unable to locate the home_controller class hence will not show it's content (if i directly include the file home_controller.php it again works as normal).

My question is, how do you map the home_controller as default, which is in a different directory?

Comment: Your current class autoloader doesn't cover classes in the `app/controller` directory. You need to setup autoloading for that specific directory. You know how, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) for installing the package. It's  standard way in PHP.

#### 1. Install Composer

- [Here is manual](https://getcomposer.org/download/), depending on your OS

#### 2. Call Composer from Command Line

Go to your root directory of your project, open Command Line and type:

```
composer require altorouter/altorouter
```

You'll find the package name `altorouter/altorouter` in `composer.json` on Github page of package - [here](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter/blob/master/composer.json#L2).

#### 3. Add loaded files to your `index.php`

Now you have installed router package. Next step is adding all composer loaded files to your application. Just replace `include 'library/altorouter.php';` with following:

```
<?php

# index.php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

#### 4. Load Your Controllers by Composer as well

Last step is tell composer where to **find your classes**.

Open `composer.json` and add following section:

```
{
    "autolaod": {
        "classmap": ["app"]
    }
}
```

Read more about [`classmap` option in documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap).

To update `/vendor/autoload.php` with this option, just call from command line:

```
 composer dump-autoload
```

That should be it. If you come at any troubles, let me know which point.

Comment: thank you ... I did not follow any of the steps up top. I accept your answer and will get back to you after I am done. thank you.